# "Time stratified" regression model?

Tags: regression, time-series, references, model

I'm sure this type of model has a name but I can't for the life of me find the correct keyword to look it up.

For each $t \in \{0, 1, \ldots, T \}$, suppose I have $n$ data tuples $\{ (X_{0,t}, Y_{0, t}), (X_{1,t}, Y_{1,t}), \ldots, (X_{n,t}, Y_{n, t}) \}$. What would be an appropriate method by which to estimate a model of the form
$$
 Y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \beta_2 X_t + \epsilon_t\ ?
$$
I suppose I could simply take a mean over the $n$ points at each time step and estimate
$$
 \overline{Y}_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \beta_2 \overline{X}_t + \epsilon_t\ ,
$$
but I wonder if there is a more sophisticated approach. Any insight is appreciated.